# Jigsaw cuts crooked when trying to rip enginered wood

Tags: powertools, laminate-floor, saw, cutting, engineered-flooring

Cack handed DIY amateur here.. I need to cut engineered wood planks lengthwise - they're 4mm oak on a 10mm MDF base. I'm having trouble getting a jigsaw to cut straight. With a "clean wood" blade the jigsaw almost immediately starts bouncing up and down vertically, even with a tight hold on the saw it feels like it's about to fly off. With a standard wood blade the saw stays down, but the cut veers off to the right in a banana shape. I've tried clamping another piece of wood to the top to steer the runner against and clamping the whole thing to a table, but it doesn't seem to help. I'd be grateful for any advice. Am I using the wrong tool maybe?

Comment: Wider jigsaw blades are less prone to bending.

Comment: Also see: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/51300/should-my-first-power-saw-be-a-circular-or-jig-saw

Comment: If this is flooring, the core is probably Hdf (high density fiberboard), which is rough on all saw blades. If you're stuck with a jigsaw, you might try a blade specially designed for flooring. (Just an example -- not one I've used -- Bosch T101BIF.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are, IME, IMHO, using the wrong tool, definitely.

- A (sharp) hand ripsaw would be preferable.
- A circular saw would be preferable.
- A bandsaw would be preferable.
- A tablesaw would be ideal

...but a circular saw is far less expensive than a tablesaw and still pretty capable with a rip guide.

Comment: Hire a table saw from a local tool hire firm. You will not regret the quality of finish it gives on the flooring panels.